# Excel Apply filter for select multiple minutes in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, excel-formula

Column has Date with Hours & minutes `(Ex:2018-02-16T00:00:20.488Z[UTC])`. I want to Filter data every 30 minutes using VBA.

For Ex, first iteration should give me all data between 00:00 to 00:30 minutes of data. I tried the below code;

```
Dim t As String
t = "T0"
cnt = 4

For n = 1 To 23
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$1000000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
    ">=" & FromTime & t & n & ":00", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:=" <= " & FromTime & t & n & ":30"
Next n
```

When ran, filter will be applied see image

[image].

Data will not be filtered. However, manually if i change from And to Or I get all relevant data.

What is wrong with my Code?

Comment: Try using the `TimeSerial()` function as here http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/autofilter-date-times.htm.  I think the issue is somehow with the date construction as a string.  Also, changing to OR basically makes it catch everything I think.

Comment: What does it say in the formula bar when you select a cell containing `2018-02-16T00:00:20.488Z[UTC]` ?

Comment: Nothing. Same content is displayed.

Comment: Are you planning to convert the strings-that-look-like-datetimes anywhere in the near future?

Answer (score 2):

> Column has Date with Hours & minutes (Ex:2018-02-16T00:00:20.488Z[UTC]).

No, it does not. You have a column with a bunch of strings that represent coded date, time and timezone information; something like a Twitter feed timestamp. In order to deal with the pieces as real dates and real times (optionally offset to the local timezone) you will have to parse out the information.

It is probably best to parse and convert the strings-that-look-like-datetimes to actual datetimes¹ before you do any further work but you can run through the strings, parsing to true datetimes on-the-fly and collect matching strings in a dictionary. The dictionary's key values can be used as an array to filter the time column.

[image]

```
Option Explicit


Sub reqwews()
    Dim dict As Object, k As Long, sr As Variant
    Dim str As String, tmp As Variant
    Dim sdt As Long, stm As Double, tm As Double, mns As Long
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbBinaryCompare
    
    With Worksheets("sheet12")
        sdt = .Cells(9, "E").Value2
        stm = .Cells(9, "F").Value2
        mns = .Cells(9, "G").Value2
        sr = Application.Match(Format(sdt, "yyyy-mm-dd\T") & Chr(42), .Columns("A"), 0)
        If IsError(sr) Then Exit Sub
    
        For k = sr To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            str = .Cells(k, "A").Value2
            If DateValue(CStr(Split(str, Chr(84))(0))) = sdt Then
                tm = TimeValue(Left(Split(str, Chr(84))(1), 8))
                If tm >= stm And tm < (stm + TimeSerial(0, mns, 0)) Then
                    dict.Item(str) = DateValue(CStr(Split(str, Chr(84))(0))) + _
                                     TimeValue(Left(Split(str, Chr(84))(1), 8))
                ElseIf tm >= (stm + TimeSerial(0, mns, 0)) Then
                    'if the datetimes are in ascending order there is no point in going further
                    Exit For
                End If
            ElseIf DateValue(CStr(Split(str, Chr(84))(0))) > sdt Then
                'if the datetimes are in ascending order there is no point in going further
                Exit For
            End If
        Next k
        
        If CBool(dict.Count) Then
            If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
            With .Cells(1, "A").CurrentRegion
                .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=dict.keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                    If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                        'do something with filtered cells
                        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
                    End If
                End With
            End With
            'If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        End If
    
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

¹ <sub>All the code needed to parse your strings-that-look-like-datetimes to actual datetimes in in the above. I just haven't written the real datetimes back to the worksheet.</sub>

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Thank you @Jeeped.